# Syncronous http request Swift

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm using Alamofire to make a GET request. It's working just fine but it's request() method runs asynchronously, I cannot know which line is called first. I just want to know how can I make an exactly same GET request using synchronous manner.

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://localhost:2403/postedjob", parameters: ["$limit": 2, "$sort": ["id":"+1"]])
            .responseJSON { _, _, JSON, _ in
                println(JSON)
        }
```

Comment: what do you mean by this "I cannot know which line is called first"

Comment: @rounak check this out. I need to fix this operation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32191127/variable-keeps-returning-nil-swift-ios/32197241#32197241

Comment: Adopt the async programming style rather than making your own requests sync. Put the code you want to execute after the request inside the callback.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the answer that you are expecting.. but I believe it to be the correct answer. Do not do http requests in a synchronous way. You should do this asynchronously and use protocols or completion blocks to execute code after the request has finished.